# How can I pass v-model from a child component to parent component in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I use vue version 2

My parent component like this :

```
<template>
  ...
      <page-heading
        :searchChange="searchChange"
      ></page-heading>

  ...
</template>

<script>
import PageHeading from "@/views/app/report/PageHeading";

export default {
  components: {
    "page-heading": PageHeading
  },
  methods: {
    searchChange(val) {
      console.log('test search')
      console.log(val)
      console.log(this.selectedDate)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

My child component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-group>
            <Datepicker
            range
            v-model="selectedDate"
        />
        </b-form-group>
        <b-button type="submit" @click="searchChange(val)">Search</b-button>
    ...
</template>
<script>
import 'vue-datepicker-ui/lib/vuedatepickerui.css';
import VueDatepickerUi from 'vue-datepicker-ui';

export default {
  components: {
    Datepicker: VueDatepickerUi
  },
  props: [
    "searchChange",
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: [
        new Date(),
        new Date(new Date().getTime() + 9 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)]
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

When click search button, I want to get selectedDate from child component. So in the parent component, I can read the selectedDate

How do I do that?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you want to pass data from child component to parent component.

To achieve that you can make use of [Emit events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events)

It works as follows

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
  ...
      <page-heading
        @some-event="someMethod"
      ></page-heading>

  ...
</template>

<script>
import PageHeading from "@/views/app/report/PageHeading";

export default {
  components: {
    "page-heading": PageHeading
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(event) {
      console.log('test search',event) //In this event you should get the selected date. 
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-group>
            <Datepicker
            range
            v-model="selectedDate"
        />
        </b-form-group>
        <b-button type="submit" @click="searchChange">Search</b-button>
    ...
</template>
<script>
import 'vue-datepicker-ui/lib/vuedatepickerui.css';
import VueDatepickerUi from 'vue-datepicker-ui';

export default {
  components: {
    Datepicker: VueDatepickerUi
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: [
        new Date(),
        new Date(new Date().getTime() + 9 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)]
    };
  },
 methods:{
   searchChange(){
     this.$emit("some-event",this.selectedDate); // event emitted to parent component with selected Date
   }
 }
};
</script>
```

You emit event from child component and you check for event in parent component method, you can log event to see what you have got from child component.

When passing data from parent to child we make use of `props` but for other way around you can do it using emit events.

Hope this helps.